# Bazel + QtCreator

Tags: tensorflow, qt-creator, bazel

It seems, there is no "standard/official" way of opening `Bazel` (the build system used to build tensorflow applications) projects in QtCreator, but have anyone figured out any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. At this [fork](https://github.com/DimanNe/tensorflow/tree/DimanNe/tensorflow/cc/DimanNe) of TensorFlow you can find a workaround of QtCreator support. The following features are tested and work:

- building project with (Ctrl+B)
- running with (Ctrl+R)
- text highlighting
- locator (Ctrl+L)
- code navigation (F2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I found some time to play with it and here is my early version of the Bazel support plugin for Qt Creator: https://bitbucket.org/knuckles/qtc-bazel-plugin/

Again, it's in early stage but it can be used to open a Bazel WORKSPACE, see targets and sources in the project explorer view, and build arbitrary targets.

It's still a WIP and lacks a few features, but feel free to give it a try - it may be enough for simple projects.

Comment: do you plan to update this plugin? with QtC 9.0, you have deprecated APIs in it and cannot build.

Comment: @xerdink it's been a while and I haven't seen much interest in the community, so at some point I've discontinued the development. But I might find the time for small updates to keep it in a functional state.

Comment: @xerdink, I updated the code to work with 9.0 :)

Comment: yes I saw, thank you. I'll contribute to this project when I have some time. great work!

Answer (score -2):

I know this is not what you're asking, but there is Bazel plugin for IntellijIdea: https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij.